# Start function on ajax success only once

Tags: jquery

I need to call a function after page load, but only once, page elements are loaded  by Ajax, so `$(document).Ready()` does not work. Now I'm using `$(document).AjaxSuccess()` but it is not rational because the function is called too often, but I needed only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the function in the [callback function](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp) of your Ajax function.

For example if you're using [jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), you should do:

```
$(".element").load("/myUrl", function(){
   //add function call here..
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.one()` [(Docu here)](http://api.jquery.com/one/). Like the name says, this only gets executed once.

Sidenote:

`.Ready()` won't work, it's called `.ready()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
      ....
   });
});
```

this will call only once since ajax call will only make when the first load the page.